# What is the subject of verb "has plummeted"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> Meanwhile, federal aid to public water utilities, which serve around
> 87% of people, has plummeted while maintenance, environmental and
> health threats, climate shocks, and other expenditures have
> skyrocketed.

What is the subject of verb has plummeted, and how can I identify subject-verb agreement in this type of sentence?

Comment: The **federal aid** has plummeted. The sentence means that government subsidies to the water companies have decreased, but the companies' costs have increased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Meanwhile, federal aid to public water utilities, which serve around
> 87% of people, has plummeted...

The subject is: "federal aid to public water utilities." What probably confuses you is the addition of a supplement " which serve around > 87% of people", which interrupts the main clause; the sentence without a supplement would be:

> Meanwhile, federal aid to public water utilities has plummeted...

Comment: Yes, but the relative clause "which serve around 87% of people" is a supplement, and supplements are not, of course, dependents.